# How to create a simple feature to detect sentiment of a sentence using CRFs?

Tags: crf++, crf

I want to use CRF for sentence level sentiment classiciation (positive or negative). But, I am lost on how to create a very simple feature to detect this using either CRFsuite or CRF++. Been trying for a few days, can anyone suggest how to design a simple feature which I can use as starting point to understand how to use the tools.

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of CRF are you using? The stanford CRF or crf algorithm provided by other open sources?

Answer (score 0):

You could start providing gazetteers containing words separated by sentiment (e.g. positive adjectives, negative nouns, etc) and so using CRF to label relevant portions of the sentences. Using gazetteers you can also provide lists of other words which won't be labeled themselves, but could help identifying sentiment terms. You could also use WordNet instead of gazetteers. Your gazetteer features could be binary, i.e. gazetteer matched or not matched. Check out http://crfpp.googlecode.com for more examples and references.
I hope this helps!